# Конкурентное чтение из списка

Tags: java, arraylist, concurrency

Является ли кеш со следующей реализацией потокобезопасным для чтения? 
Кешируемые данные хранятся в статическом списке `list`. Реализация заполнения кеша гарантирует, что обновление кеша c использованием `updateCache` будет проходить неконкурентно. При обновлении кеша в качестве буфера используется локальная переменная `temp`. Доступ к элементам кеша осуществляется извне осуществляется через итератор - `getIterator`. Псевдокод кеша

```
class Cache {
  /** Список, хранящий кешированные данные */
  private static volatile List list;

  /* Обновить кеш */
  public static void updateCache() {
    // Буфер
    List temp = new ArrayList();
    // Заполнить буфер из БД ...
    list = temp;
  }

  /** Получить итератор по кешу */
  public static Iterator getIterator() {
    return list.getIterator();
  }
}
```

Можно ли утверждать, что раз операция присваивания является атомарной, то кеш потокобезопасный для чтения?

Comment: Нет, не будет, в данном члучаи будет наблюдаться гонка потоков и некорректное получение данных

Comment: @GenCloud почему?

Comment: @GenCloud, где будет гонка?

Answer (score 1):

Реализация потокобезопасна, т.к. итератор работает с экземпляром листа, а не с его ссылкой. В данном случае Вы не модифицируете лист, а просто атомарно перезаписываете ссылку на него на новый экземпляр листа. Если это произойдет во время итерации - итератор будет возвращать значения из листа, из которого он был создан, т.о. Вы будете получать неактуальные данные. Т.е. после вызова updateCache() нужно будет заново вызывать getIterator();